# iPhone background files downloading

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, background, download

Is there any way we can download files on iPhone on background? I.e. I want to start the application, specify files to be downloaded, then send application to the background and later, when data are downloaded get some notification?

Regards,
STeN

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your application;

- You can start a background thread (10 minutes maximum execution time, or until the system decides to kill your application), this is possible for all applications.
- You can use Newsstand to get even more background time (semi-unlimited). But this is only usable for digital magazines.